# Cannot comment on answers other than mine

Tags: support, comments

I cannot comment on answers other than mine, the link "Comment" is only visible for my answers.

Is it a matter of the reputation score (as "Downvoting" is)?

Thanks!

Comment: Question answered: I needed 50 points =). Until today I had 45, and someone voted one of my answers and now I'm 55 =D. Thanks!

Comment: faq http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work

Answer (score 2):

If you mean on StackOverflow. Yes

On Meta you can comment on anything. On StackOverflow, SuperUser or Serverfault, you must have 50 reputation to comment.*

<sup>*</sup> Except on your own questions, your own answers, and any answers to questions you've asked. You can comment on your own "stuff" with 1 rep.

See the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)